# Is there a way to see documents shared with me using Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there a chance to display documents shared with me in a Webpart? I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: Is this is what you require: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/49b76d83-4827-4713-9666-0e381d0c3049/ssharepoint-2013-shared-with-me?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: i don't see the solution there